# Can I install tiles directly over a concrete floor in my basement?

Tags: basement, tile

We are redoing our basement.  In some areas (bathroom and laundry room) I plan on putting tile down.  The basement is dry and level.   Can I attach the tile directly to the basement floor?

Comment: What kind of tile?   Vinyl, ceramic, etc?

Comment: Probably ceramic (12x12 or similar), something that can take foot traffic and is not too costly because it is just a basement.

Comment: You may want to consider installing an in-floor heating system to keep the floor warm in the winter.

Comment: @RSMoser - Good idea, although I am trying to keep costs down. There is baseboard heating installed already in the main room (which will be the kids playroom), but not in the bathroom.

Comment: @JonRaynor: We have a small baseboard in our bathroom and just always keep the door closed.  If i could have floor heating, I would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can - and even if the floor is slightly irregular, your application of thinset can even the top layer and make it nice and solid and true.

Here's an example - my own basement (not done by me - in fact about to be removed by me - but still...)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why not.

It would be worth sealing the concrete to make it waterproof where you are going to tile, particularly as you are making a bathroom and laundry room where there'll be a high risk of water spillage.

Answer (score 4):

Schluter Systems recommends using [DITRA](http://www.schluter.com/5502.aspx) between the concrete and tile, but of course they sell DITRA, so they are not impartial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, I would add a modifier to the thinset (instead of water) to make it flexible and bond well.